# dynamic key in mapping Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hi i have an JSON object like this :

```
WorkTime=[{
      "Day": "6",
      "Time1": "8 : 00 - 9 : 00",
      "Time2": "9 : 00 - 10 : 00",
      "Time3": "10 : 00 - 11 : 00",
      "Time4": "11 : 00 - 12 : 00",
      "Time5": "12 : 00 - 13 : 00",
      "Time6": "13 : 00 - 14 : 00",
      "Time7": "17 : 00 - 18 : 00",
      "Time8": "18 : 00 - 19 : 00",
      "Time9": "19 : 00 - 20 : 00",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "Day": "0",
      "Time1": "8 : 00 - 9 : 00",
      "Time2": "9 : 00 - 10 : 00",
      "Time3": "10 : 00 - 11 : 00",
      "Time4": "11 : 00 - 12 : 00",
      "Time5": "12 : 00 - 13 : 00",
      "Time6": "13 : 00 - 14 : 00",
      "id": 2
    },]
```

and i want insert object's Value into My div . but i should write the Object key and my Number of Keys is Variable. for this i decide to use index and dynamic call Keys but i don't know anything about its Syntax  .
What I want to do is almost like this :

```
 {
                   WorkTime.map((item, index) => (
                  <div key={index} id={`Ticket${item.Day}Box`} className="bg-gray-50 p-3 w-11/12
                   rounded-t-xl mx-auto" style={{ display: "none" }}>
                    {item.Time{index+1}} 
                  </div>
                )) }
```

instead Of Call Keys Like This :

```
WorkTime.map((item, index) => (
                  <div key={index} id={`Ticket${item.Day}Box`} className="bg-gray-50 p-3 w-11/12
                   rounded-t-xl mx-auto" style={{ display: "none" }}>
                    {item.Time1} 
                  </div>
                )) }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can use the brackets syntax and string interpolation to get what you want:

```js
item[`Time${index + 1}`]
```

I'm assuming you do realize that this will only give you the first time entry from every `WorkTime` object. If you want to show all the time entries, you'll have to iterate over them separately. For this I'd recommend changing the structure of your json to something like this:

```js
WorkTime = [{
  id: 0, // whatever
  day: "day string",
  times: ["time 1", "time 2"] // etc
}]
```

It modifying json is not possible, then you can collect all the `Time` keys with this:

```js
Object.keys(item).filter(k => k.match(/Time\d/))
```